# Adding main class from a .jar folder

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to create an Extension which will parse language(which is written with my grammar) and find it's faults.

so I create my main class in Server and import it in VSCode. **How can I access my main class from Client?**

this is my launch.json:

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch) with Arguments Prompt",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "mainClass": "",
            "args": "${command:SpecifyProgramArgs}"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "protocol": "legacy",
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 9229
        },


    ]
}
```

my main class path --->>>  /Desktop/intellijden eclipse-->VScode/vscode-languageserver-java-example/Server/app.class

but my server in .jar.